# Flexbox layout inside Bootstrap menu width issue in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, flexbox, submenu

I'm trying to learn how to use flexbox and get the flexbox to display correctly in Chrome & Firefox inside a Bootstrap submenu, but the child menu panel doesn't calculate the width correctly. It pretty much never expands horizontally and the menu items just spill out over the boundary of the menu. When viewed in a recent version of IE, the menu looks like it should work, but doesn't work in Chrome/Firefox/Opera.

This is the structure of the menu with multiple ul's inside the dx-menu-container-wrap div (only showing one for brevity).

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid"> <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>

        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="dropdown"> <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a href="#">More options</a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <div class="dx-menu-container-wrap">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <p><strong>Category 1</strong>

                                            </p>
                                        </li>
```

And then the CSS is:

```
.dx-menu-container-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    white-space:nowrap;
    height:400px;
}
```

Do I need to do something different to get the width of the menu to expand to accommodate the flexbox container in Chrome and Firefox?

Desired behavior of the menu: 
Have a fixed height of 400 px, have the ul's fill in vertically first starting in the left column, and expand/flex out to additional columns in the right direction starting from the leftmost position.

*Works in IE

http://jsfiddle.net/cjsmith/2287nv0o/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a min-width to your dropdown wrapper like this:

```
.dx-menu-container-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    white-space:nowrap;
    height:400px;
    min-width:300px;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle of the flexbox dropdown with a min-width: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/2287nv0o/11/

It seems to be working fine on Chrome, FF as well as IE too